# Capturing the contents of native prototypes

Tags: javascript

Try and do the following:

```
for (var key in String.prototype)
    console.log(key);
```

It gives you...nothing (well, unless you defined some foreign stuff yourself.) However, you still have `String.prototype.split` for example. I tried it on every other native object (`Number`, `Array`, `Object`) for the same result.

The following also "doesn't work":

```
for (var key in Array)
    console.log(key);
```

While there's `Array.isArray` for example.

`Object.keys(Array.prototype)` gives an empty array, and so does `Object.keys(Array)`. However, `Object.keys(jQuery)` for example provides a giant array, as expected.

So, why can't we iterate over natives provided by the browser, yet still access them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [MDC page for `for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

> A `for...in` loop does not iterate over built-in properties

The reason is that properties in Javascript are either enumerable or non-enumerable; "enumerable" means you can access the property in a `for..in` loop.  All built-in properties are non-enumerable.

Modern browsers support the `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` method:

```
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Array.prototype));
// ["length", "constructor", "concat", "map", "sort", "join", "indexOf", "filter", "some", "toString", "reduceRight", "splice", "forEach", "shift", "unshift", "toLocaleString", "lastIndexOf", "reverse", "reduce", "pop", "push", "every", "slice"]
```